# Find value in column of MySQL table and print return

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `cars` and inside I have two fields `year` and `chat_id`

I have two records inside:

```
2019 | 1234
2018 | 1111
```

How can I search inside table `chat_id == 1234` and return `1` if exist else `0`?
How can I print this?

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
$chat_id= 1234;

$query= "SELECT IF(chat_id == $chat_id,0,1) AS return FROM cars";
$return_id= mysqli_query($connection, $query);
print_r($return_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysqli_num_rows` to check if the record exists and `WHERE` clause to filter the results.

```
$chat_id= 1234;

$query= "SELECT chat_id FROM cars WHRE chat_id = '$chat_id'";
$return_id= mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($return_id);
echo $rowcount; // Will return total number of rows matched else will return zero
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for existence you do not need to select any data from the DB. You can just fetch 1 if it exists otherwise it will return `NULL`. Also you should always remember to use prepared statements and never inject PHP variables into SQL queries.

```
$chat_id = 1234;

$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM cars WHERE chat_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $chat_id);
$stmt->execute();
// fetch the first column from the first row as an integer
$return_id = (int) $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row()[0];
```

Another option is to use `bind_result` as can be seen in this article: [How to check whether a value exists in a database using mysqli prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/check_value)